# how do I fix this error? ReferenceError: totalSupply is not defined

Tags: error-handling, solidity, chai, truffle, referenceerror

Im using a course, and I got this error:

```
ReferenceError: totalSupply is not defined
```

and Idk what it means by that, cause I never got this error before.
can somebody help me fix this error? thanks
and this is my code:

```
const { assert } = require("chai");

const KryptoBird = artifacts.require("KryptoBird");

// check for chai
require('chai')
.use(require('chai-as-promised'))
.should()

contract('KryptoBird', (accounts) => {

    let contract
    before( async () => {
    contract = await KryptoBird.deployed()
    })
    
    
    
    describe('deployment', async() => {
        it("deploys successfully", async () => {
            const address = contract.address;
            assert.notEqual(address, '')
            assert.notEqual(address, null)
            assert.notEqual(address, undefined)
            assert.notEqual(address, 0x0)
        })
        it('has a name', async() => {
            const name = await contract.name()
            assert.equal(name, 'KryptoBird')
        }) 

        it('has a symbol', async() => {
            const symbol = await contract.symbol()
            assert.equal(symbol, 'KBIRDZ')
        })

    }) 

    describe('minting', async ()=> {
        it('creates a new token', async ()=> {
            const result = await contract.mint('https...1')
            const totalSupply = await contract.totalSupply();
            assert.equal(totalSupply, 1)
            const event = result.logs[0].args
            assert.equal(event._from, '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 'from is the contract')
            assert.equal(event._to, accounts[0], 'to is msg.sender')

            await contract.mint('https...1').should.be.rejected
        })
    })

    describe('indexing', async()=> {
        it('lists KryptoBirdz', async()=> {            
        // Mint three new tokens
        await contract.mint('https...2')
        await contract.mint('https...3')
        await contract.mint('https...4')
        const totalSupply = await contract.totalSupply()
        })

        let result = []
        let KryptoBird
        for(i = 1; i <= totalSupply; i++) {
            KryptoBird = await contract.kryptoBirdz(i)
            result.push(KryptoBird)
    }

    let expected = ['https...1','https...2','https...3','https...4']
    assert.equal(result.join(','), expected.join(','))

})

})
```

if u need another contract, just tell me, and if u could help me, thanks so much, because I need to finish this today. I've been trying to fix this for 2 hours, it didnt work. so please, if u could help me, it would mean a LOT to me.

here:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import './ERC721Connecter.sol';

contract KryptoBird is ERC721Connecter {

    string[] public kryptoBirdz;

    mapping(string => bool) _kryptoBirdzExists;

    function mint(string memory _kryptoBird) public {
        
        require(!_kryptoBirdzExists[_kryptoBird],
        'Error - kryptoBird already exists');

        // this is deprecated - uint _id = KryptoBirdz.push(_kryptoBird);
        kryptoBirdz.push(_kryptoBird);
        uint _id = kryptoBirdz.length - 1;

        // .push no logner returns the length but a ref to the added element
        _mint(msg.sender, _id);
         _kryptoBirdzExists[_kryptoBird]=true;


    }
    

constructor() ERC721Connecter('KryptoBird','KBIRDZ')
{}

}
```

Comment: `totalSupply is not defined` -  Seems like `totalSupply` isn't defined. Do you know which line is causing the issue?

Comment: no, it isnt showing which one.

Comment: Perhaps this one: `for(i = 1; i <= totalSupply; i++) {
            KryptoBird = await contract.kryptoBirdz(i)
            result.push(KryptoBird)` ? I'm not sure, but it seems like that `totalSupply` may be out of scope?

Comment: you are calling this: ` contract.totalSupply()`. that means the contract does not have `totalSupply()`. you either did not impleent `totalSupply` or you made typo

Comment: I don't get it @Yilmaz

Comment: Can you share your smart code?

Comment: is this what u mean? @Kerry99